# want to delete temporary files on weblogic programmatically

Tags: java

Hi while uploading the file using the  weblogic server. The temporary file of the file to be uploaded is getting created on the folder `E:\WL\user_projects\domains\AMS_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\GenesisDenmark\3m840e\public`.

If I upload test.zip then that is being copied on the above location with the name test.tmp. I want to delete it programmitcally.
I am using struts 1.1.

If anybody has done something similar to it. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may because of some other reason. you really want to programmatically delete? I may be wrong(Please let me know if so) but you can use a regular expression to match all the temporary files. But better approach will be if each time on uploading any file take the file name, Search for the file having the same name and .tmp extension. Represent that file by a File object, try to get programmatically if that particular file exist delete that file.(In struts you should do it in Action class or if you are using spring/EJB along with struts you should do this in your business logic.)
I think you'll need to do following steps

```
 1. Fetch the uploaded file name(As I think it will be with extension)
 2. get a substring of this file name upto the last location of . (to
    get the file name without extension)
 3. append .tmp in that file name
 4. check the condition if that file exists in your uploading directory
 5. if so, delete the file
```

Some sample code, I hope it may help you:

```
        //Get the servers upload directory real path name
          filepath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"xml_upload";
          System.out.println("The file path is "+filepath);
          //create the upload folder if not exists
           File folder = new File(filepath);
           if(!folder.exists())
           {
            folder.mkdir();
           }


     MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(req,filepath);
     ff=m.getFile("f");
     System.out.println("Full Path with file name:"+ff);
     //get file name...
     filename=ff.getName();
     System.out.println("file name is:"+filename);

      //now here you have to get the file name without extension and then append the extension .tmp
 // now let the file is represented by a File object say ff .....

   if(ff.exists())
          {
           System.out.println("File exist and it is going to delete.");
           ff.delete() ;
           }
```

For one of my XML upload application I used he same, as xml data will updated and new values will be displayed and if user want to discard the updation made by xml file on clicking over discard button it will revert the changes and delete the uploaded xml file.

Comment: Hey Shailesh thanks for your help. But I just checjked that the temp files get deleted on its own after some time. My issue is to delete the cache/ history of the browser before uploading the file. Because my task is to upload a huge file but as the broswer or the form already contains huge data it gives multipart error while uploading the file( that is my understanding of getting multipart error).

Comment: There may be some other reasons too for multipart error.
As make sure you are keeping enctype=multipart/form-data in your form tag. Second thing is to clear the browser's cache memory you can use

 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 09 April 2013 00:00:00 GMT"> 
in your head tag
and use <%
   response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
   response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
   response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
%>  in each jsp where you want to clear cache on load.

Comment: <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 System.out.print("first"); response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server %> <nested:form action="/dataUploadActionNew" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 System.out.println("second one"); response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server %>

Comment: I have used the above tag in my code. But I suppose these tags are for not letting my file to be cached. I want to delete previously present cache. So that form is not heavy.

Comment: "want to delete previously present cache"

As  best of my knowledge that doesn't make sense! As for once you can do it manually and after that it will not store anything in cache because you set the headers for not to store it in cache.

You can check these links:
http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache
http://java.com/en/download/help/webcache.xml
If it don't help you Please let me know. As you are welcome any time.

Comment: We can't delete cache everytime we upload the file. The basic aim is to delete all the information stored in the form/broswer page sothat the form becaomes light.We can't tell everybody to clear the cache by going to Internet options. We have to do it programmitically only. I want to do it beacuse when I try to upload the file it gives me the multipart error and after deleteing the cache it works most of the times. Sometimes my code works sometimes doesn't. If you have any better solution for multipart error then please help, as I am facing this issue only.

Comment: The code should work all the time but even after deleteing the cache of broswer it doesnt work. Does anybody faced the same problem as I am facing?